# jQuery Click Event only works in Landscape (iPhone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have been asked to patch up a rather badly written responsive website at work, and have been left stumped by an issue with a jQuery click event.

The event works fine on iPhone in Landscape mode, but in Portrait mode it doesn't do anything.

Here's the jQuery:

```
if (width <= 480) {
    function menu(e) {
        e.PreventDefault();
        $('#menu-item-93 .sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    }

    $('.nav-cont').addEventListener('click', menu(e));
    $('.nav-cont').addEventListener('touchstart', menu(e));
}
```

And the section thats relevant from the header.php file (did I mention, this is a Wordpress site)

```
<nav id="main" class="main clearboth">
    <?php 
        wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
            'theme_location' => 'primary', 
            'after'=>'<img src="'.template_url('images/button/link-445x68.png').'" class="show-480" />'
        ) );
    ?>
</nav>
<div class="nav-cont">
    <div class="nav-text show-480">NAVIGATION</div>
    <img class="nav-button show-480" src="<?php echo template_url('images/button/navigation-closed-nt-445x52.png');?>" />
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea why this touch event only fires in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in the end by going through multiple javascript files left by the old development agency who were working on the site.  I found that there were multiple instances of click handlers on this selector which were contradicting each other.  I removed the others and bam, it worked.

It even worked in the way I originally intend for it to work with a basic

```
$('.nav-cont').click(function() {
});
```

event handler.

Comment: You gotta hate old developers who don't clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your code starts with `if (width <= 480) {`. This looks like it can be valid portrait but not in landscape, making the problem right there.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo at the end there, it's been updated now to say landscape, as it should.  `if (width <= 480) {` shouldn't cause any issues, this is the same boundary as defined in a media query to trigger the mobile layout, which works fine.

Comment: So basically, it's only running the javascript in the mobile layout, and the iphone work fine within the constraints.

Comment: But can you try replacing width <= 480 with true or 1==1 just to see if this is the problem? Just to make sure this is out of the way

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
$('.nav-cont').addEventListener('click', menu(e));
$('.nav-cont').addEventListener('touchstart', menu(e));
```

should be:

```
$('.nav-cont').addEventListener('click', menu);
$('.nav-cont').addEventListener('touchstart', menu);
```

or even:

```
$('.nav-cont').on('click', menu);
$('.nav-cont').on('touchstart', menu);
```

The current code adds the result of calling the `menu` function to the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike, this unfortunately didn't fix the issue.  Surely though, if the event handler I have was invalid it wouldn't fire in landscape mode either?  Or in desktop browsers that have been resized for that matter.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code. There may be other attached event handlers that are bound in other conditions. For instance, maybe there is an `addEventListener` for the same button which is attached in some other instance? Also, I've never seen `addEventListener` used on a jQuery object like that. Shouldn't it be `$('.nav-cont').on('click', menu);`?